# Open XML adding images in multiple picture content controls

Tags: c#, openxml, office-2010

ok, old question is gone and this is new one:

@JasonPlutext, we decided to do it the way you suggested. custom xml looks like:

```xml
<DATA>
    <BLOCK>
        <FNAME>Test</FNAME>
        <LNAME>Test1</LNAME>
    </BLOCK>
    <PICTURE>
    <SIG> domain\username</SIG>
    </PICTURE>
</DATA>
```

Text controls are binded: `$rowBlock.FNAME`, `$rowBlock.LNAME` and picture content control is `$rowPicture.SIG`.
text from xml is displayed, but there is no picture...

Picture is returned by ws (web service input parameter is `domain\username` from `<sig>` and picture is returned as `byte[]`).

```cs
//this is part of code where dealing with picture content control
picture[] pic = getPic("domain\username");
Paragraph tP = new Paragraph();
ParagraphProperties tParagraphProperties = 
    pControl.Descendants<ParagraphProperties>).FirstOrDefault();
tP.ParagraphProperties = (ParagraphProperties)tParagraphProperties.Clone();
...?...
```

Please suggest what to do next and how to bind picture?
thx

Comment: You need to put the picture bytes base64 encoded into your custom xml part, and you need a databinding element in your picture content control sdtPr.  Then open the file in Word to check you are doing this correctly ... if you are, you should see your image on the document surface.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a slightly different approach.

You can bind a picture content control to an element in a custom xml part which contains a base64 encoded image.

If you do it this way, you can rely on Word to resolve the binding (ie update the image on the document surface with the one in the custom xml part).  Or you can mimic what Word does yourself; [docx4j.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j.NET/3.0.1) contains code to do that for you.

Doing it this way becomes a matter of just updating the custom xml part with the images you want.

Comment: Jason, thx for help but my boss said that this is no the right solution :) I'm now searching in different direction: 1.find all picture content controls, 2.find position of each control and read tag, 3. delete content control and insert picture in same position. I think this can be done :)

Answer (score 0):

Jason, i'm injecting base64 encoded image content as you said, but there is still no picture. in customXml folder of zip document, in item3.xml there is a base64 string inside  tag, but in media folder there is only default image. don't know what's wrong... my procedure is:

//first, searching for drawing inside current processing control

```
`Drawing tDraw = pControl.Descendants<Drawing>().FirstOrDefault();

//if there is a drawing element, then clone control
OpenXmlElement tClone = (OpenXmlElement)pControl.Clone();
//then call method: 
 private static void insertPicture(OpenXmlElement pControl)
    {
        //WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(dokument, true);
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = dokument.MainDocumentPart;
        CustomXmlPart customPart = mainPart.CustomXmlParts.FirstOrDefault();

        //convert image into string
        string picName = @"c:\temp\picasso.png";
        System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(picName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(fileStream);
        byte[] byteArea;
        byteArea = br.ReadBytes(System.Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));
        string picString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteArea);

        //Load the XML template
        string DataString = iData["DATA"].ToString();
        //Properties.Resources.XMLData;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(DataString);

        //change the value
        XmlNodeList xmlNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("picture");
        xmlNode[0].InnerText = picString;

        //write the custom xml data into the customxmlpart
        System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(customPart.GetStream(System.IO.FileMode.Create), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.WriteRaw(xmlDoc.InnerXml);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();

        fileStream.Close();
        br.Close();

        mainPart.Document.Save();
        //dokument.Close();
    }

then append control to document
OpenXmlElement tC1 = pControl;
            IEnumerable<Run> tEl1 = tClone.Descendants<Run>();
            if (tEl1.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (OpenXmlElement tElement in tEl1.Reverse())
                {
                    OpenXmlElement tClone1 = (OpenXmlElement)tElement.Clone();
                    tC1.InsertBeforeSelf(tClone1);
                    tC1 = tClone1;
                }
            }`
```

Comment: When i applied your code, my word file instead of showing the image it shows the `Base64String` of the image. Any idea on why this happens?